# UITableView performance difference between Iphone 3G and 3GS?

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, iphone-3gs

I managed to put my new app on an adhoc distribution but I just noticed that I only have 3GS's ...

It is working quite good on the 3GS (could be a bit faster but that's fine) ... but do you think I should test it on the 3G ?

I know there has been a lot of improvements between 3G and 3GS but would that infer on my uitableview performance ?

Thanks,

Gotye.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely test it physically on all the platforms that you say the application will run on.

If you don't have access to all the models, then I can suggest you gather a small group of testers at [iBetaTest.com](http://www.iBetaTest.com).

Comment: I have two itouch : one model MC008LL and one model MA627LL, do you know which one would be closer to an iphone 3G ?
Cheers